# How to insert the div html inside the jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask how to insert div html inside the jquery (var fieldHTML)? Below is my code.

html

```
<div class="field-wrapper">
<div class="field-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="left">
        <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">+</a>
</div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 3; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field-wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div class="field-wrapper">
<div class="field-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="left">
        <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field">-</a>
</div>
</div>'; //New input field html
```

more here:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yingchor/Lzaf2wve/1/)

All suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't just post a link to your code, and wrap in in code syntax to avoid the "no code no fiddle" rule

Comment: First suggestion is to use the site properly by providing a [mcve] ***in the question itself***. Take some time to read [ask]

Comment: I don't understand what the question is about - you could make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzaf2wve/2/) with solution.

The only issue I am seeing in your code is that variable `fieldHTML` in javascript. This variable is not taking your HTML as a string. So giving below error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Just convert that HTML to string and everything will work fine.

```
var fieldHTML = '<div class="field-wrapper"><div class="field-wrapper-inner"><div class="left"><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/></div>  <div class="right"><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field">-</a></div></div>';
```

Comment: Mayur Patel, thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has two methods to append the content:

```
.append( content [, content ] )
```

Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements. ([read more...](http://api.jquery.com/append/))

and the second one:

```
.appendTo( target )
```

Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target. ([read more...](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/))

The first one is simple, it appends content right after the element, i.e.,

$('.field-wrapper-inner').append(fieldHTML);

this one will append the code right after `<div class='field-wrapper-inner'>...</div>`.

If you want to place the code inside the div, before the closing `</div>`, then you need append your element to this div, but your element should be a jQuery object, not just a string. To make it a jQuery object, just wrap it with `$()`, i.e., `var fieldHTML = $('my HTML code');`, and then append it to another jQuery element:

```
fieldHTML.appendTo($('.field-wrapper-inner'))
```

This one will place the element inside `<div class='field-wrapper-inner'>...</div>`, right before the closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
var fieldHTML = '<div class="field-wrapper">
<div class="field-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="left">
        <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field">-</a>
</div>
</div>'
    $('.field-wrapper').append(fieldHTML);

    });
```